# Init an object as global

Tags: python, global

Is there a clever way to init objects as global?  So when I create an object like:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        global self
        super(A, self).__init__()
```

this obviously doesn't work, but I'm curious if there's a nice way to handle this like `g` in flask.

Comment: Objects are not global, local, or anything; they all exist on the heap. *Names* have scope.

Comment: but could you make an object that when init, it makes itself global

Comment: No, because the *object* is not global; whatever name you *assign* the object to has a scope, but that information isn't available to the `__init__` method.

Comment: You probably looking for something like _singleton_. This or really troublesome design.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, that don't work with self because self is a parameter in your constructor.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        global instance

        instance = self
        super(A, self).__init__()


A()
instance
<__main__.A at ...>
```

This may only used in really really edge cases, I don't see any case where that would make sense.

Note this is only working if an instance is created. If you don't want the instance but the raw class, you can mark the class name as global:

```
global A
class A(object):
    pass
```

Comment: This creates *one* global name that refers to an instance of `A`. Each time you call `__init__`, the instance that `instance` refers to changes.

Comment: @chepner Of course, this is why I said "I don't see any case where that would make sense.".

Comment: @tobias_k Not if you define a class inside an other definition

Comment: this is helpful though.  It's not for actual code, it's just for teaching how to global works.  I wouldn't do something like this in production.

Comment: one issue is you can't give the name of the variable as input, like: `class MyGlobal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        global name;
        name = MyObject(value)`

Comment: @Rob You could do: `global name; name = self.__class__`

Comment: You should not mark a name as global after you have assigned to it. The `global A` should come *before* the class definition.